# "Cлышать запахи"

Tags: этимология, грамотная-речь

А вот интересно, почему говорят "СЛЫШАТЬ запахи"? Мы видим предметы, слышим звуки, осязаем прикосновения, но запахи почему-то тоже слышим.

Comment: Dear Passionario.

Я не "слышу запахи", зато чую запах костра в лесу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Глагол СЛЫШАТЬ многозначный. Одним из значений является '*распознавать путём ощущения; ощущать, чувствовать, замечать*'. Поэтому возможны такие словосочетания: *слышать запах, аромат; слышать сердцем, душой; слышать угрозу, слышать беду; земли под собой не слышать*
('испытывать сильную радость, быть в восторге'); *не слышать ног под собой*
('испытывать чрезмерно сильную усталость от бега, ходьбы или восторга'); *себя не слышать* 
('забывая всё, горячо, полностью отдаваться чему-л., какому-л. чувству').

Answer (score 4):

Вполне согласна с первым значением. Добавлю, что одни скажут  - слышать запахи, другие - чувствовать, оба варианта верны. Но  у того человека, который "запахи слышит" - больше развита слуховая система восприятия, он так называемый аудиал. Тот. кто запахи чувствует - кинестетик.

Comment: Моя бабушка (юг Западной Сибири) употребляла слово "чуять" в смысле "воспринимать органом слуха". В местности, откуда я родом, "слышать" вообще практически не говорили.

Comment: Это сильно зависит от окружения: как в комменте выше моего сказано, если в регионе принято говорить определенным образом, то и люди приучаются говорить с детства определенным образом, потом это очень сложно меняется. Про аудиалов и прочее все сказано давно, например вот хорошая статья аггрегирующая данные 2004 года: https://qz.com/585143/the-concept-of-different-learning-styles-is-one-of-the-greatest-neuroscience-myths/ С удовольствием заминусовал бы, но не могу пока.